# How to upgrade laravel 5.1 to 5.6?

Tags: laravel, upgrade

I want to upgrade laravel on my website from 5.1 to 5.6, please tell me how it is possible?

Comment: you need to update step by step 5.1 -> 5.2 -> 5.3 -> 5.4 -> 5.5 -> 5.6.. if you want it fast.. just go here https://laravelshift.com/

Comment: In my experience the jump in auth scaffolding and the routing service provider from 5.2 to 5.3 is big and it may be worth rebuilding into a new instance. It actually might even be faster to rebuild your code onto a fresh Laravel instance. There are also other major several jumps and pivots between the versions.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the upgrade guides here https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade
Start with 5.2 and work your way up to 5.6 or 5.7 that was released a few days ago.

I had to upgrade a 5.1 app before and I ended up just creating a new blank Laravel 5.5 project (latest at the time) and copying over everything from the old app starting with the route folder. Don't just copy them over, make sure you move each file individually to avoid breaking something. You should definitely be prepared to spend an hour or so on it.

Comment: thanks for suggest try it. but there is no other way borther.??